# Playback drops frames or stutter on good hardware

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm planning to use TDARR and trying to prevent any issues before with (re)encoding. And I have stumbled on issue with one TV Show - recently I have downloaded refreshed old show but playback stutters on TV or drops frames (few frames every few secs - so video plays nicely but suddenly few frames are droped and then for next few secs it plays nicely - no issues with sound)

I guess this particular video has some options which causes issues or I don't know but here are some facts I have gathered (ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams):

1. The TV is capable of playing FullHD HECV 10bit smoothly https://pastebin.com/0efSGjk9
2. Original video stutters https://pastebin.com/vvLn8y4a
3. Converted video (QSV) stutters (linux/ffmpeg https://pastebin.com/XbazLEft
   Below cutout part of script parameters for converting - $FPS is supplied as without it ffmpeg does not create I Frames but that is not a problem here)

```
        -hide_banner -y -init_hw_device qsv:hw \
        -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv \
        -i "$FILENAME_BACK" \
        -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
        -c:v hevc_qsv -preset slow -global_quality 22 -g $FPS\
        -c:a copy \
        -movflags faststart "$FILENAME_OUTPUT"
```

4. Converted video (NVENC) plays nicely (win/handbrake) https://pastebin.com/HbBNMZvT - present can be found here https://pastebin.com/tZqCuAWC

In the end I wish I could create "safe" parameters list which I will supply to TDARR and not to worry about issues while converting videos.

Forgot to mention - Hardware on which Im planning to mass encode has Intel proc with QSV capabilities - I'm not planning to encode on NV.

If needed - I can provide any other information.

Comment: Very unlikely, but still possible to be an overheating issue.

Comment: It could just be in the video itself. Does it always happen at exactly the same place? Can you play the video in other players and get the exact same issue? It happens that someone created the video by playing the video in a protected environment and then used screen capture, and the lag you see was during the recording on their hardware.

Comment: Hey, it stutters on AndroidTV Plex or VLC (original+QVS encoded) while it plays nicely if NVENC encoded. On webbrowser on PC all versions plays nicely